# Background colour for form label and radio button

Tags: php, html, css

I have set up a form that allows users to sort by date, Asc or Desc.

So far, I have figured out how to let a user:

1) Select a radio button.

2) Keep the radio button selected after submit.

3) Display a written message to the user of their choice.

**The HTML / PHP Code:**

```
<p>Sort by Date:</p>
    <form action="" method="post" class="date">
        <input type="radio" name="dateorder" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="ascending" <?php if (isset($_POST['dateorder']) && $_POST['dateorder'] == 'ascending') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /> <label for="ascending">Newset &rsaquo; Oldest</label><br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="dateorder" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="descending" <?php if (isset($_POST['dateorder']) && $_POST['dateorder'] == 'descending') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /> <label for="descending">Oldest &rsaquo; Newset</label>
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['dateorder'])){
            echo "Date Order: " . $_POST['dateorder'];
        }
    ?>
```

I would like to visually show the users selection by adding a colour background when selected. The background colour should span both the radio button and label. Is this possible with CSS?  So far this is what I have, only the label gets colour/style applied:

```
<head>
    <title>Practice Radio Buttons</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    p{font-weight: bold;}
    form input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;}
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: `a + b` selectors style only `b`, not `a` too. Plus, styling radio buttons is famously difficult. Most styled radio buttons these days are pseudo radio buttons (plenty of tricks for this - Google it.) Easiest way would be to put the input and label in a container, and give that a background instead of the elements themselves.

Comment: Okay, thanks Utkanos, like a div or something.  Shall try and see how I go.

Comment: To change background color, of course CSS is one piece that you might need, but also jQuery with the $(yourstuff).css("background-color","yellow");  and ".click(change()"

Comment: Yeah, just seeing that, no clue of jQuery.  How would I code this with what I have.

Comment: I have come across this code, how should it be applied? Thanks for any help:  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
       $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for, not by actually styling the radio button, but by playing around with the positioning (and `padding` and `z-index`) of the `label`.

1. apply `position:relative` to both elements;
2. ensure each radio button has a higher `z-index` than its label;
3. apply to the `label` a *negative* `margin-left` value (moving it left);
4. apply to the `label` a *positive* `padding-left` value (moves the label text right);

Now the left-hand side of each label is ***underneath*** its radio button.

Consequently, when you click the radio button, the highlit background will now surround the radio button *and* its label text.

**e.g.**

```css
label, input[type="radio"] {
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
}

input[type="radio"] {
z-index: 12;
}

label {
z-index: 6;
padding: 10px;
padding-left: 40px;
margin-left: -30px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="date">
<h2>Sort by Date:</h2>

<input type="radio" name="dateorder" id="ascending" value="ascending" />
<label for="ascending">Newest &rsaquo; Oldest</label>

<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="dateorder" id="descending" value="descending" />
<label for="descending">Oldest &rsaquo; Newest</label>

</form>
```

Comment: Really cool, Rounin, good lateral thinking there.  Thanks very much ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
label {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: relative;
  right: -1.5rem;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
   background: red;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio"><label>i'm label text</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the hover selector?

Something like

```
<style type="text/css">

label:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro.  I tried it, but it is not what I am looking for.  When a user clicks a radio button option, the background colour should change.